# How to add navigation button to a Select component (MUI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, html-select

So i'm having this `Select` component from MUI and it works fine as it is. After selecting an item from the list, the router pushes to that location:

This is the code:

```
export default function SelectLocation({
  countriesData,
  currentUrl,
  formColor,
}: any) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handelChange = (e: any) => {
    router.push(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    //@ts-ignore

    <StyledFormControl formColor={formColor}>
      <Select
        value={countriesData ? currentUrl : "loading"}
        id='server-select'
        onChange={handelChange}
      >
        {countriesData ? (
          countriesData.map((country: any) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem value={country?.attributes.Slug} key={country.id}>
                {country.attributes.Country} - {country.attributes.City}
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <MenuItem value='loading'>Loading...</MenuItem>
        )}
      </Select>
      <FormHelperText>Select another server location</FormHelperText>
    </StyledFormControl>
  );
}
```

What i want is to add two navigation button (Prev, Next) which navigates accordingly to the next/previous item in the list.

[image]

I'd appreciate any idea which leads me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily if you make the array of the options you are using and then map it inside select and when onChange triggers set the index value to the value you selected then when you click on next then increment the index by one and on previous do vice versa